# Regular expression for tag item (class) in html

Tags: html, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm rather new to python and programming ;-), and I'm writting a programm for scraping data from the web-site that has over 6000 lines for only 1 page, while I'm going to scrape about 20000 thousands of them. I'm using python 2.7.4

I have seen some tutorials on how to use regular expressions but it did not work for me.
I'm using Beautiful Soup for finding particular tags, actually I need to find such tags:

```
<tr class="room_loop_counter1 maintr">
<tr class="room_loop_counter1 extendedRow">
<tr class="room_loop_counter2 maintr odd">
<tr class="room_loop_counter2 extendedRow odd">
<tr class="room_loop_counter3 maintr">
<tr data-occupancy="2" class="room_loop_counter1 ">
<tr data-occupancy="2" class="room_loop_counter2 odd">
<tr data-occupancy="3" class="room_loop_counter3 ">
<tr data-occupancy="3" class="room_loop_counter4 odd">
```

etc. I'm not sure about space infront of quotes after room_loop_counter1,3.

I was trying to write an expression that would fit next line of code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_part)

av = soup.find_all('tr', class_=REGULAR_EXP)

REGULAR_EXP = re.compile('"room_loop_counter"\d\s.')
```

but I obviously write wrong regular expression for class

How to write one that will be valid?
I suppose that it should be an expression that findes all "room_loop_counter" followed by any  number of characters (numbers, spaces,letters, but not new line character)
Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use a DOM library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex **finds all "room_loop_counter" followed by any number of characters (numbers, spaces,letters, but not new line character)** :

```
room_loop_counter[A-Za-z\d\s]*
```

Your regex `"room_loop_counter"\d\s.` matches `"room_loop_counter"` (note the enclosing quotes) followed by a digit, followed by a space and then any character.

So it matches `"room_loop_counter"1 x` and `"room_loop_counter"3 !` but not `"room_loop_counter1"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a dot(`.`), which means one character, in the end use a `.*`, which means any number of characters. That should do the trick. So your code will become:

```
REGULAR_EXP = re.compile('"room_loop_counter"\d\s.*')
```